# Apache .htaccess mod_rewrite RewriteCond Problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to get a RewriteCond/RewriteRule pair working, which results in a 404 error unless I uncomment the RewriteCond, in which case everything is redirected.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/
RewriteCond /var/www/site/downloads/$1 -F
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ getdownload.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The idea is, if the file exists in the downloads directory to send the user to the getdownload.php script, which distributes the download, assuming they have permission.

Any thoughts as to why this would be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule path/downloads/(.*) path/downloads/getdownload.php? [L]
```

Still shows downloads/index.php in URL, but serves /downloads/getdownload.php content, AND makes sure it's a file. (note: my .htaccess file is in the top level of my test site.)

If you want to put it into /downloads/ you can delete "path/downloads/" from both sides of the rule.

Comment: This seems to be doing the opposite of what I need--I need the file to not exist, but rather exist in the downloads directory in which case the script getdownload.php (not in downloads) is rewritten to.

Comment: If I understand you right, then all you would need to do is remove /downloads/ from the last part of the rule. At that point Apache should say, "visitor is requesting a file (which exists) in path/downloads/, therefore I'll point them to path/getdownload.php". With or without the Cond above, you'll get a 404 if the file doesn't exist in /downloads/. By adding the Cond, the Rule is only fired if a file truely does exists in /downloads/ - essentially killing page calls one script sooner.

Comment: `RewriteRule path/downloads/(.*) path/getdownload.php? [L]`